# Find all solutions to the functional equation $f(x+y)-f(y)=\frac{x}{y(x+y)}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Find all solutions to the functional equation
>   $f(x+y)-f(y)=\cfrac{x}{y(x+y)}$

I've tried the substitution technique but I didn't really get something useful.

For $y=1$ I have

$F(x+1)-F(1)=\cfrac{x}{x+1}$

A pattern I've found in this example is that if I iterate $n$ times the function $g(x)=\cfrac{x}{x+1}$  I have that $g^n(x)=\cfrac{x}{nx +1}$ ,which may be a clue about the general behaviour of the function ( ?) .

I am really kinda of clueless ,it seems like the problem is calling some slick way of solving it.

Can you guys give me a hint ?

Comment: What can $x,y$ be? Anything as long as $y(x+y) \neq 0$?

Comment: As the question is stated in my book,it doesnt make any restrictions .

Comment: Then we should assume that $x,y$ are real and $y\neq0$, $x+y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=1-y$, hence $x+y=1$.

Then we get $$f(1)-f(y)=\frac{1-y}{y}$$

I will include the full solution in a spoiler, since you only asked for a hint.

> This gives $f(0)=c$ and $f(1)=d$, then $f(y)=\frac{y-1}{y}+d$ for all other $y$. 
> This simplifies to $f(0)=c$ and $f(y)=\frac{y-1}{y}+d$ for all other $y$.  We have to check whether every such function satisfies. Note that neither $y$ nor $x+y$ can ever be zero, so $f(0)$ can indeed be anything.  Now we have to check the other values: Does 
>  $$\left(\frac{x+y-1}{x+y} + d\right) - \left(\frac{y-1}{y} +d \right) = \frac{y}{y(x+y)} ?$$  $$\frac{y(x+y-1)-(y-1)(x+y)}{y(x+y)} = \frac{y}{y(x+y)} ?$$ 
>  It turns out that the functions do satisfy the functional equation.

Comment: Give me some time to fully comprehend the meaning of it.

Comment: @Mr.Y Sorry I mistyped it. Now the equation is the correct one and you should now be able to solve it. There are a few tricky parts left.

Comment: If I rearrange your hint I have that $f(1)-f(y)=\cfrac{1}{y}-1$ from which I see ,matching terms,that the requested function is $f(y)=-\cfrac{1}{y}$ since $y$ can be any value.Is this a bad way to extrapolate the solution ?

Comment: @wythagoras: Why are you entitled to assume that $x +y = 1$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson We may assume that $x=1-y$ since $x,y$ can be anything but those satisfying $x+y=0$ and $y=0$. Rearranging $x=1-y$ gives $x+y=1$.

Comment: @Mr.Y We do not know whether $f(1)=1$. So the required solution is $f(y)=\frac{y-1}{y}+f(1)$.

Comment: @wythagoras why do you state that $f(0)=c$ isn't $f(0)$ undefined,since we have that for $y=0$ and $x+y=0$ we have a division by $0$ ?

Comment: $f(0)$ itself is defined, but we can't substitute it into the functional equation.

Comment: $f(0)$ is *not* defined. However, what you have is enough: $f(y) = 1+d-\frac1{y}$ gives you what you want. See my answer for a simpler way.

Comment: @martycohen I'm afraid I will disagree. If we are given that $f$ is a function form $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $f(0)$ can be anything, since the functional equation does not give any information about $f(0)$. But your answer is really nice.

Answer (score 8):

$f(x+y)-f(y)
=\cfrac{x}{y(x+y)}
=\frac1{y}-\frac1{x+y}
$
so
$f(x+y)+\frac1{x+y}
=f(y)+\frac1{y}
$.

Therefore,
$f(x)+\frac1{x}$
is constant,
so
$f(x)
=d-\frac1{x}
$
for some $d$.

Substituting this,
the $d$s cancel out,
so any $d$ works,
and the solution is
$f(x)
=d-\frac1{x}
$
for any $d$.

Comment: This is also really neat.Thank you marty cohen.I love when I get many beautiful answers on one question.I wish I could accept all of your answers. :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 5):

Another approach: I assume that $f$ is a function of a single real variable.Write the defining equation as $\frac{f(y+x) - f(y)}{(y+x)- y} = \frac{1}{y(x+y)}$
(for $x,y,(x+y) \neq 0).$ Take the limit as $x \to 0$. On the one hand this limit is $\frac{1}{y^{2}}.$ On the other hand, the limit is, by definition, the derivative $f^{\prime}(y)$, (and we have proved that this exists for $y \neq 0$).
An antiderivative of $\frac{1}{y^{2}}$ is $\frac{-1}{y}$. Hence $f(y) = \frac{-1}{y} + C$ for a constant $C$, as long as $y \neq 0$. (Strictly speaking this proves that any function $f$ which satisfies the equation has to be of the described form. It should be checked that such functions satisfy the equation- but they do).

Comment: This is really a total different way to look at the problem,really neat !!Thank you Geoff Robinson!

Comment: The answer by Marty Cohen is more direct though!